# Product_id not being passed to function

Tags: laravel

I have this form

```
   <form method='POST' action='/products/{{ $product->id }}/reviews'>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
         <div>
            <textarea name = 'review' placeholder ='Post a review'>{{ old('review') }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type ='submit'>Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The data then gets passed to this function in my controller

```
    public function store(products $product)
    {
         $product->addReview(request('review'));

         return back();
    }
```

The addReview method is found in my products model

```
 public function addReview($review)
    {
        return reviews::create([
            'product_id' => $this->id,
            'review' => $review
        ]);
    }
```

I think the problem lies here
`'product_id' => $this->id,`
Once I fill in the form and submit, no data is added to the 'product_id' field. It's not included in any of the post data.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between your `review` and the `product`?

Comment: In my products model I have
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(reviews::class);
    }

and in my reviews model 

   public function products()`
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(products::class);
    }

Comment: but a Review, belongs to a product, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, have I not set it correctly? 

$this(products)->hasMany(reviews::class)
and
$this(reviews)->belongsTo(products::class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Review model:

```
public function product() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(products::class); 
}
```

I renamed it to a `product` because it is one result not multiple.

Then here:

```
public function addReview($review)
{
    return reviews::create([
        'product_id' => $review->product->id,
        'review' => $review
    ]);
}
```

Or even better, if you are adding a review, you should have the Product selected not the review, as you are adding a review to the product, so the method should be something like this:

```
public function addReview($product)
{
    $review = request('review');

    return $product->reviews()->create([
        'review' => $review
    ]);
}
```

**EDIT** I see that you already have this.. so this code should work. If in the `reviews` table you have a `product_id` column, the relationship should be correct.

Comment: I'm afraid I got the following error
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object

Which relates to 'product_id' => $review->products->id

Comment: @zgrav, did you changed the method name as I mentioned above.. why using `products`? Is your column named `products_id`, or `product_id`?

Comment: Hi, I changed to product and I'm still facing the same problem. 
The column is named 'product_id'

Comment: And you use this: `$review->product->id`? Your error means that there is no product for the `$review`. so this code `$review->product` returns `null` so you cannot call `id` on `null`. Have you tried my second method implementation because that's what you should use actually.. In the form you are posting a Product ID, not a REVIEW.

Comment: The issue was due to not having product_id in the $fillable field in my reviews model.
Sorry for the wasted time.